# Laravel - Min Date and Max Date failed to Update

Tags: laravel

Using Laravel-5.8 for my web  application, I have this code in my controller:

```
public function store(StoreAppraisalGoalRequest $request)
{
    $validated = $request->validated();             
    $userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id;
    $employeeId = Auth::user()->employee_id;
    try {
        $goal = new AppraisalGoal();
        $goal->goal_type_id             = $request->goal_type_id;
        $goal->employee_id              = $employeeId;
        $goal->weighted_score           = $request->weighted_score;
        $goal->goal_title               = $request->goal_title;
        $goal->goal_description         = $request->goal_description;  

        $goal->save();       

        foreach ( $request->activity as $key => $activity){
            $startDate = Carbon::parse($request->start_date[$key]);
            $endDate = Carbon::parse($request->end_date[$key]);

            $goaldetail = new AppraisalGoalDetail();

            $goaldetail->activity                   = $request->activity[$key];  
            $goaldetail->start_date                 = $startDate ->toDateTimeString();
            $goaldetail->end_date                   = $endDate->toDateTimeString();                 
            $goaldetail->appraisal_goal_id          = $goal->id;
            $goaldetail->save();
         }

         $min_date = AppraisalGoalDetail::select('start_date')->where('appraisal_goal_id', $goal->id)->orderBy('start_date', 'asc')->first();
         $max_date = AppraisalGoalDetail::select('end_date')->where('appraisal_goal_id', $goal->id)->orderBy('end_date', 'desc')->first();


         $goal->update([
             'appraisal_start_date' => $min_date,
             'appraisal_end_date'   => $max_date
                 ]);

            Session::flash('success', 'Appraisal Goal is created successfully');
            return redirect()->route('appraisal.appraisal_goals.index');
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
            Session::flash('danger', 'Appraisal Goal creation failed!');
            return redirect()->route('appraisal.appraisal_goals.index');
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve is that as soon as I submit, I want the application to pick minimum date from AppraisalGoalDetail (start_date) and maximum date from AppraisalGoalDetail (end_date)

Then quickly update the values of appraisal_start_date and appraisal_end_date in the AppraisalGoal as shown below:

```
     $goal->update([
         'appraisal_start_date' => $min_date,
         'appraisal_end_date'   => $max_date
             ]);
```

I found out that it didnt do the update. Why?

And what do I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$min_date` and `$max_date` are objects. You need to get their attributes like this:

```php
$min_date = AppraisalGoalDetail::select('start_date')->where('appraisal_goal_id', $goal->id)->orderBy('start_date', 'asc')->first();
$max_date = AppraisalGoalDetail::select('end_date')->where('appraisal_goal_id', $goal->id)->orderBy('end_date', 'desc')->first();


$goal->update([
   'appraisal_start_date' => $min_date->start_date,
   'appraisal_end_date'   => $max_date->end_date
]);
```

And the  efficient way is use `max()` and `min()` to get the value:

```php
$min_date = AppraisalGoalDetail::where('appraisal_goal_id', $goal->id)->min('start_date');
$max_date = AppraisalGoalDetail::where('appraisal_goal_id', $goal->id)->max('end_date');

$goal->update([
   'appraisal_start_date' => $min_date,
   'appraisal_end_date'   => $max_date
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
$min_date = AppraisalGoalDetail::select('start_date')->where('appraisal_goal_id', $goal->id)->orderBy('start_date', 'asc')->first();
$max_date = AppraisalGoalDetail::select('end_date')->where('appraisal_goal_id', $goal->id)->orderBy('end_date', 'desc')->first();
```

this code return an instance of `AppraisalGoalDetail` (of course with only the selected field filled).
You need to recover only the value of the field. Like this

```php
$min_date = AppraisalGoalDetail::where('appraisal_goal_id', $goal->id)->orderBy('start_date', 'asc')->value('start_date');
$max_date = AppraisalGoalDetail::where('appraisal_goal_id', $goal->id)->orderBy('end_date', 'desc')->value('end_date');

$goal->update([
    'appraisal_start_date' => $min_date,
    'appraisal_end_date'   => $max_date
]);
```

When using the method `value('fieldName')` it will select only the field name provided and limit the request to 1 and return the field value as is (no mutator)